# ld verification of load/store fails when using LTO but not much info is provided

Tags: macos, llvm, ld, xcode10

After updating to Xcode 10 our C++ codebase does not link when built with -Os and -flto. The following error is provided:

`ld: Explicit load/store type does not match pointee type of pointer operand (Producer: 'APPLE_1_1000.11.45.2_0' Reader: 'LLVM APPLE_1_1000.11.45.2_0') for architecture x86_64`

(the same error occurs on the latest Xcode 10.1 Beta 3)

The same code builds fine with Xcode 9. Sadly the linker does not provide any more info than spitting out the above error message. Some info about the object file would be helpful in trying to pinpoint the exact source of the problem. Removing -flto eliminates the error…

Does anyone have any debugging suggestions/ideas? We've tried to use "--trace" with ld to get more info on the files being processed but the error message just gets outputted in the middle of the trace with no apparent correlation between the error and the input file being printed at that moment.

This all smells very much of a compiler error and I've reported this to Apple via the bug tracker.

Any extra help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case turning any optimization -O1,2,3 spit out this error (while -flto was off)
I tracked it to the following issue.
I made a class Algo_three - so that I can return 3 values from a function:

```m
@interface Algo_three<T,V,W> : NSObject{
@public
    T p_0;
    V p_1;
    W p_2;
}

+ (Algo_three<T,V,W>*) first:(T) f second:(V) s third:(W) t;
@end
```

And I used it as follows (in .m file)

```m
+(Algo_three<NSManagedObjectContext*,NSManagedObjectContext*,NSError*>*) CreateCDContexts: ....
{
    return [Algo_three first:ui_managedObjectContext second:sync_managedObjectContext third:nil];
}
```

Receiving 3 values - this was good as well..

```m
Algo_three<NSManagedObjectContext*,NSManagedObjectContext*,NSError*> * two_contexts = [not_important_class CreateCDContexts: ... ];

//and here is accessing
self->ui_context = (NSManagedObjectContext*) two_contexts->p_0; //getting 1st value
self->sync_context = (NSManagedObjectContext*) two_contexts->p_1; //2nd value
```

Commenting out last two lines removed the error!
So I added three accessor properties to class Algo_three and it worked.
Algo_three class lookes like this (.h).

```m
@interface Algo_three<T,V,W> : NSObject{
@public
    T p_0;
    V p_1;
    W p_2;
}
@property (strong,nonatomic) T first;
@property (strong,nonatomic) V second;
@property (strong,nonatomic) W third;

+ (Algo_three<T,V,W>*) first:(T) f second:(V) s third:(W) t;
@end
```

Implementation of those properties (.m):

```m
- (id) first{
    return p_0;
}
-(void) setFirst:(id) obj{
    self->p_0 = obj;
}
- (id) second{
    return p_1;
}
-(void) setSecond:(id) obj{
    self->p_1 = obj;
}
- (id) third{
    return p_2;
}
-(void) setThird:(id) obj{
    self->p_2 = obj;
}
```

and instead of ->p_0 accessing is done via properties .first, .second

```m
self->ui_context = (NSManagedObjectContext*) two_contexts.first;
self->sync_context = (NSManagedObjectContext*) two_contexts.second;
```

Lastly I admit - that compiler told me what file the error was located in, albeit not so clearly.
XCode 10.1 (10B61). I scrutinised the file that was just before the compiler error - I confirmed it by running archive from command line :

```
xcodebuild -scheme MY_PROJ archive
```